# Database cursor retrieves only one row always

Tags: android, database

I am trying to retrieve the contents of database into a `List` view but not able to display them. Since the cursor contains only one item, don't know why, but it is not getting displayed in the list.

I also took reference of `ListActivity` on `developer.android` but could not solve the problem. Can some one here help me!!

I am posting my code:

```
setContentView(R.layout.simple_list_item_1);    
System.out.println("Creating db");     

mDatabase = openOrCreateDatabase(Helper.DATABASE_NAME, 
                    SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY, null);    
System.out.println("Created db");  

//String[] args= {Long.toString(id)};  

mDatabase.execSQL(Helper.CREATE_TABLE);    
System.out.println("Creating table");  

addContents();  
addContents();  
addContents();  

String[] fields = {Helper.ID, Helper.DESC, Helper.DOSAGE};  

calendarData = mDatabase.query(Helper.TABLE_NAME, fields, null, null, 
                       Helper.DESC, null, null);  

int count = calendarData.getCount();    
System.out.println("Queried db: "+count);  

startManagingCursor(calendarData);  

int[] fieldTextViews = {android.R.id.text1,android.R.id.text2};  

ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, android.R.layout.two_line_list_item, 
                              calendarData, fields, fieldTextViews);  
setListAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: please format your post..so that it could be understandable

Answer (score 0):

Sweety 
 **System.out.println** doesn't works on Android replace it by [**Log.d(TAG,msg)**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html) to see output on DDMS.

Comment: It works for me. I can see the output in logcat. Any ways thats not the problem.Can you tell me is there any problem with the query to retrieve all the records?

Comment: @sweety  Is data insertion in addContents() successful?

Comment: Yes I have 26 records in the database.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing what `addContents()` does, we don't know what the contents of the database are.. i.e. are you attempting to insert the same record three times but the second two attempts do not insert due to a conflict?

But since you appear to be using this [seven-parameter version of `SQLiteDatabase.query()`](http://bit.ly/eb2z40), you are passing the "DESC" constants as the `groupBy` parameter.  That could explain why you're only getting one result.

Presumably you want to `orderBy` that column name instead?

Comment: DESC means description.Helper class has string desc . And in addContents method I have added same record 26 times. Is this the problem? As it has multiple records with same values?

Comment: Yes, but why is the string `DESC` there at all? Currently you're causing an SQL `GROUP BY` to happen, rather than `ORDER BY` (which is what I presume you want). That you have the same record 26 times is the reason why, when GROUPed, you only see one result.